# why does the situation "client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe" occur during SSH connection in one case and does not occur in another

Tags: python, bash, perl

If I do like this (bash):

```
SSH_COMMAND="ssh -t ${LOGIN}@${HOST}"
sshpass -p ${PASSWD} ${SSH_COMMAND} "command"
```

then I get the result:
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe

and (perl):

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
my ($output, $error) = $ssh->capture2('command');
```

same result: client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe

But if I do this (python):

```
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**con_bsr)
output = net_connect.send_command('command')
```

or (bash)

```
sshpass -p ${PASSWD} ${SSH_COMMAND} << EOF
command
EOF
```

then it's all right.

I can't figure out what's the difference

Comment: Does `command` read stdin?

Comment: no, it's any command that the remote host supports, like "show version"

Comment: maybe the problem is because the device I'm connecting to gives a "banner" before and asking for a password and after authorization before "prompt"

Comment: Wouldn't in this case the Python command fail as well?

Comment: The _broken pipe_ is a hint that a session timeout occurs. SSH wants to read the stdout of the command, but the connection is suddenly closed. BTW, the two _bash_ variants you show, are virtually equivalent (except that the second one sends an additional line feed after _command_, but I don't think that this matters). What happens, if you don't supply a command, but enter it manually into an interactive ssh?

Comment: The python script is  works, but it takes a very long time (~18 sec).
If I do supply a command in interactive mode - that all right's. I don't think the command  matters.